# substituting a string inside a file that contains comment (started with ;)lines with batch script

Tags: batch-file

i have a file named "abc.ini" with contents like this:

```
;------------------------
; this file is a reffernce file
; you will get server path as below
admin_folder=E:\Temp\utils_630\admin**
VERSION=630
PORT=6304
IP of server=10.9.23.64
```

here i need to replace **utils_630** to **utils_640**
i am using the script to replace it.
But in output i am not getting the ; at the beginning of the lines as it is in the original file.
i need the file as it is with the required string replaced.
Any help on this will be appreciable.Thanks in Advance!!!!!!!!!
semicolons are the starting of line and 4th line starts with admin_folder.

Comment: You should show your code. I suspect you are having problems with the default FOR /F "eol" option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "eol= tokens=*" %%a in (abc.ini) do (
set line=%%a
echo !line! | find "utils_"
if not !errorlevel!==0 (
echo !line! | find "VERSION="
if not !errorlevel!==0 (
echo !line! >>new.ini
) else (
call :EXTRACT
)
) else (
call :EXTRACT
)
)
del abc.ini /f /q
ren new.ini abc.ini
pause >nul

:EXTRACT
set "line=!line:630=640!"
echo !line! >>new.ini
```

Comment: is it possible to replace multiple strings with different strings in side a file using one for loop or we have to write separate for loop for each??????

Comment: You would have to repeat the `find` line for each one, then just make sure the `errorlevel` is 0 for one of them before replacing. You could probably just repeat the 
else block for each one as well, if it doesn't contain it, it shouldn't change.

Comment: in the file i have a line like "VERSION=630" and i have to replace it by "VERSION=640".for that i used set command.set str1="VERSION=630" set str2="VERSION=640" and find %str1%.when i am running the script its not finding the VERSION=630 string  by showing error file not found........

Comment: is it possible to replace the string "VERSION=630" any way.i am not finding anything.need help!!!!!!!!!

Comment: I'm not really sure what your trying to do. My answer replaces 630 already? Post what you are using at the moment into your question and I will have a look.

Comment: in the above question as i have edited the file contains port numbers olso.so only changing 630 will replace the port=6304 to 6404.that is why i want to change the whole word "VERSION=630" to "VERSION=640".hope now u are clear with my purpose.

Comment: Ok, so do you want to change `PORT=6304` to `PORT=640` as well?

Comment: no if i will replace only 630 by using ur script it may change the port number also and i do not want that.i wnat only change at two places that is utils_630 to utils_640 and version=630 to version=640

Comment: Then copy the code for VERSION as well, I just ran it myself and the port isn't changed, it only changes lines matching what you specify, in this case utils_630 and then just add version=630 as well.

Comment: i tried that but the line [set "line=!line:version=630=version=640!"] is not working properly.please suggest...

Comment: Yes, I did. I have been working another way of doing it, see my updated answer, which will replace both `utils` and `version`, without repeating the `for` loop, and will leave everything else, including `port` untouched.